# How to get Python's os.path.realpath returning the 'real' path on a Windows substed drive?

Tags: python-3.x, windows

Python's **os.path.realpath**, when used with a substed drive on the Windows paltform, don't resolve the substed path to the *real* path.

For example creating a substed drive like this:

```
subst S: C:\Users\Public\Desktop
```

and checking real path in python like this:

```
import os
myPath = "S:\\"
print("Real path of: " + myPath + " is: " + os.path.realpath(myPath) )
```

prints

```
Real path of: S:\ is: S:\
```

In the docs for the [subst](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/subst) command, a substed drive is referred to as a *virtual* drive. Virtual, suggesting something being "not real", indicates that the Python *realpath* command is not working as one would assume on Windows.

The code is used to setup a Docker container and the path is used in a mount.  Docker will ask the user for permission to used the substed drive as a shared drive, which will fail, as docker can't use shared substed drives. This is why it's crucial getting the **real**, proper path.

How to get the proper path above, i.e. from **S:\\** get **C:\Users\Public\Desktop**, in Python?

Update:
After filing a Python Bugreport, word was given that there is a pull request for an updated, proper, version of realpath on Windows. In the meantime, one can use:

```
pathlib.Path('S:\\').resolve()
```

which resolves to the *real* path, i.e. c:\Users... etc!

Answer (score 1):

Currently proper answer is:

```
pathlib.Path('S:\\').resolve()
```

Thanks to Eryk Sun, see https://bugs.python.org/issue36112

Comment: FYI, subst.exe defines drives via [`DefineDosDeviceW`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-definedosdevicew). This creates devices (really object symlinks that implement bind mounts, i.e. junctions) that have arbitrary names and target arbitrary NT paths. When the path is parsed by the system, the link gets resolved to the real path. It's similar to system drives such as "C:", but subst.exe can only target a file-system directory, whereas normal drives are links to a volume device (e.g. "\Device\HarddiskVolume2").

Comment: @eryksun Yes, that means that even if OP gets the associated target for a substed drive, it may not be in the format they want.  It's a lower-level path spec than the one a Windows/DOS user is used to.

Comment: Using file-system junctions should be preferred over subst.exe because some functions such as [`GetVolumePathNameW`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-getvolumepathnamew) fail if a drive targets a file-system directory instead of a volume device. In contrast, file-system junctions are set on a directory, so it's perfectly normal for them to target another directory.

Comment: @librik, certainly that's a problem if `resolve()` depended on `QueryDosDeviceW`. But it's based on `GetVolumePathNameByHandleW` and requests a DOS path. Internally this WINAPI function uses a mountpoint-manager IOCTL to map the NT device path back to a DOS path.